# $\operatorname{lcm} (a,b)$ of rectangle's side lengths

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rectangles, least-common-multiple

Knowing that the dimensions of a rectangle $ABCD$, $a$ and $b$ are proportional to $3$ and $5$ respectively and that their area is equal to $135~\text{cm}^2$, find the $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$.

(I already know the result, but I want to know how to do it step by step)

Comment: Did you mean to write $LCM$ for least common multiple?

Comment: Also, you should explain what you have done.  In doing so, you may answer your own question.

Comment: Yes, least common multiple. I thought his would could be done like: LCM (3,5).. which would result in 15. But the answer to this question is 45. And I don't know how to get to this.

Comment: What did you obtain for the side lengths of the rectangle?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to upload an image containing the rectangle, but failed cause of my reputation. The a = 3 is for the widht and the b = 5 is for the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Knowing that the dimensions of a rectangle $ABCD$, $a$ and $b$ are proportional to $3$ and $5$ respectively and that their area is equal to $135~\text{cm}^2$, find the $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$.

**Strategy:**

1. Since the side lengths $a$ and $b$ are proportional to $3$ and $5$, respectively, let $a = 3x$ and $b = 5x$.
2. Since the area of rectangle $ABCD$ is equal to $135~\text{cm}^2$, $ab = (3x)(5x) = 135~\text{cm}^2$.
3. Solve for $x$ to determine $a$ and $b$.
4. Find $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$.

Judging by your answer in the comments, you did not take into account the fact that the side lengths are *proportional* to $3$ and $5$ and did not notice that the area of the rectangle you obtained with side lengths $3~\text{cm}$ and $5~\text{cm}$ does not have the required area of $135~\text{cm}^2$.